# SQL Server 2008 select with regular expression

Tags: sql, regex

I have an SQL Server 2008 database with a table called "page_data" that contains a NVARCHAR column called "path"

The path column will contain data like the follwoing:

```
/aaa/bbb
/aaa/bbb/zzz
/aaa/ccc
/aaa/ccc/xxx
/aaa/ddd
/aaa/ddd/yyy
```

I want to select rows where the path data only contains two slashes. So I should get the following data returned:

```
/aaa/bbb
/aaa/ccc
/aaa/ddd
```

I can't think of how to do this. Can anyone help?

Comment: The answer is in your headline. Why don't you just do some research (a.k.a. 'googling' or 'binging' or even SO'ing) on the term 'SQL-Server 2008 regular expression'?

Comment: I have, but can't find anything.

Comment: There are articles describing that you have to write a .net assembly providing the feature which can then be linked into SQL-Server and used as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
;with T as (
    select 0 as row, CHARINDEX('/', Col) pos, Col from page_data
    union all
    select row + 1, CHARINDEX('/', Col, pos + 1), Col
    from T
    where pos > 0
)
select distinct MIN(Col1) Col
from(
    select 
         row,
         Col,
         (case when row=2 then SUBSTRING(Col, 1, pos-1) else Col end) Col1
    from T 
    where pos > 0 and row<3
)x
group by Col
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77dfd/1)